Chrome Docker image works locally but fails on server
I am building a Docker image that includes Chrome.
The image works perfectly on my local machine, but when deployed to a server, Chrome fails to start with the following error:
[301:301:1224/210431.755768:WARNING:chrome_main_delegate.cc(672)] This is Chrome version 131.0.6778.204 (not a warning)
[301:301:1224/210431.756051:VERBOSE1:chrome_crash_reporter_client.cc(206)] GetCollectStatsConsent(): is_official_chrome_build is false so returning false
[301:301:1224/210431.764222:VERBOSE1:chrome_crash_reporter_client.cc(206)] GetCollectStatsConsent(): is_official_chrome_build is false so returning false
[308:308:1224/210431.801474:VERBOSE1:cdm_registration.cc(287)] Registering bundled Widevine 4.10.2830.0
[309:309:1224/210431.801499:VERBOSE1:cdm_registration.cc(287)] Registering bundled Widevine 4.10.2830.0
[308:308:1224/210431.802020:INFO:cpu_info.cc(53)] Available number of cores: 8
[309:309:1224/210431.802353:INFO:cpu_info.cc(53)] Available number of cores: 8
[308:308:1224/210431.802507:VERBOSE1:zygote_main_linux.cc(201)] ZygoteMain: initializing 0 fork delegates
[309:309:1224/210431.802725:VERBOSE1:zygote_main_linux.cc(201)] ZygoteMain: initializing 0 fork delegates
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)


Chrome version: linux-131.0.6778.204
Flags: --no-sandbox --headless --disable-setuid-sandbox --enable-logging=stderr --v=1

Why is Chrome running locally, but not on the server with exactly the same configuration? My understanding was that the images are supposed to be "identical"...
How can I access the core dump?

What are Docker versions on the local machine and on the server?

Local Docker version 27.4.0, build bde2b89;
Remote Docker version 27.4.1, build b9d17ea

Does the local machine and remote server use the same platform (linux/arm64, linux/amd64, windows/amd64) ?

Local and remote use the same platform linux/amd64, but different OS. Local is 6.12.4-1-MANJARO, remote 6.8.0-50-generic #51~22.04.1-Ubuntu.
I've even tried to build the image locally and load it manually onto the remote machine - no success.
